# Ampscript GET view_email_url

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Hello I have a problem with an ampscript code I can not get the online version and send it in salesforce cf the following code:

```
%%[
var @contactId, @campaignId, @id, @contactRows, @limitRow, @nom, @HTML
set @id = id_etudiant
set @nom = 'Alerte'
set @campaignId = '7011t000000Hl6AAAS'
set @contactRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Account', 'PersonContactId','Id', '=', @id)
set @limitRow = Row(@contactRows, 1)
set @contactId= Field(@limitRow, 'PersonContactId')


IF _messagecontext == "SEND" Then
set @HTML = HTTPGet(view_email_url)
    CreateSalesforceObject(
       'CampaignMember', 3,
       'CampaignId',@campaignId,
       'ContactId',@contactId,
       'Status','Sent')
 CreateSalesforceObject(
     'Tracking_automation__c',3 ,
       'MessageName__c ',@nom,
       'Contact__c',@contactId,
        'Version_en_ligne__c',@HTML

)
EndIF   
]%%
```

The version without the online url works :

```
%%[
var @contactId, @campaignId, @id, @contactRows, @limitRow, @nom
set @id = id_etudiant
set @nom = 'Alerte'
set @campaignId = '7011t000000Hl6AAAS'
set @contactRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Account', 'PersonContactId','Id', '=', @id)
set @limitRow = Row(@contactRows, 1)
set @contactId= Field(@limitRow, 'PersonContactId')


IF _messagecontext == "SEND" Then

    CreateSalesforceObject(
       'CampaignMember', 3,
       'CampaignId',@campaignId,
       'ContactId',@contactId,
       'Status','Sent')
 CreateSalesforceObject(
     'Tracking_automation__c',2 ,
       'MessageName__c ',@nom,
       'Contact__c',@contactId


)
EndIF   
]%%
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this is blocked because HTTPGET on a view online link has the potential for an infinite loop.

Comment: Okey, maybe, but What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `HTTPGET` to get the URL for `view_email_url`. Simply set it as a variable.

```
%%[
var @contactId, @campaignId, @id, @contactRows, @limitRow, @nom, @HTML
set @id = id_etudiant
set @nom = 'Alerte'
set @campaignId = '7011t000000Hl6AAAS'
set @contactRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Account', 'PersonContactId','Id', '=', @id)
set @limitRow = Row(@contactRows, 1)
set @contactId= Field(@limitRow, 'PersonContactId')


IF _messagecontext == "SEND" Then
set @HTML = view_email_url
    CreateSalesforceObject(
       'CampaignMember', 3,
       'CampaignId',@campaignId,
       'ContactId',@contactId,
       'Status','Sent')
 CreateSalesforceObject(
     'Tracking_automation__c',3 ,
       'MessageName__c ',@nom,
       'Contact__c',@contactId,
        'Version_en_ligne__c',@HTML

)
EndIF   
]%%
```

Comment: Thanks jackson, I have already test and it's doesnt work. The support team tell me it's better to try to ubdate a data extention because it's my case it's will be create an infinite look up..